How to associate Web Roles to Contact from with in Power Pages (Enhanced Data Model)
In Enhanced data model the relationship between Contact and Web Role is actually between Contact and Site Component entity as Web Role is a virtual table.
In our Contact form copy we insert a subgrid with name grid_contact_mspp_webrole that lists the Active Web Roles view of Web Roles table.
In Basic Form Metadata of a new Contact table, we create a subgrid for grid_contact_mspp_webrole to make the actual data link (this is required by Power Pages)
In Power Pages we give proper permissions for Web Role Table and to Site Component Table through existing powerpagecomponent_mspp_webrole_contact relationship.
The problem is that we always see all roles on every contact in the subgrid and not the associated contact role.
We are expecting to see only the associated contact roles per contact.
Related issue Regarding associating web roles to contact from Power Pages Portal does not give specific details of the solution.
